# How to get column values from an excel using only column name?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to read a set of usernames and password from an excel sheet. My user name is present in the First column but my password values are present in the 8th column. I don't want to read the 8th column values by giving the 8th column address. Instead i want to read the password values wherever I place it in the excel sheet. Is there any way to do this ?

> FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(strReadFile);
>         Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
>         Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
>         int rowCount=sh.getRows();
>         System.out.println("No of Rows:"+rowCount);
>
> ```
>   for(int row=1;row<rowCount;row++) {
>       String Username = sh.getCell(1,row).getContents();
>       driver.findElement(By.id("user_name")).sendKeys(Username);
>
>
>       String Password = sh.getCell(2,row).getContents();
>       driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys(Password);          
>       driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click(); 
>    }
> ```

Comment: Do you only Put Username And Password only?

Comment: Yes. i have the username and password in an excel sheet. As u can see in the code above im getting the user name values by specifying the location of the value. But instead i want to get the values by specifying the column name so that when i specify the column name, all the values under should get read one by one. Is it possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt method As per my understanding. Check below method column for your solution.

```
    for(int row=1;row<rowCount;row++) {
      String Username = sh.getCell(column("username column",sh),row).getContents();
      driver.findElement(By.id("user_name")).sendKeys(Username);


      String Password = sh.getCell(column("password column",sh),row).getContents();
      driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys(Password);          
      driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click(); 
   }


public int column(String columnName, Sheet sheetAt) throws Exception{
    Row row = sheetAt.getRow(0);

    int col = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
        if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
            continue;
        }
        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            String text = cell.getStringCellValue();
            if (columnName.equals(text)) {
                col = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (col == -1) {
        throw new Exception("None of the cells in the first row were Patch");
    }

    return col;
}
```